# RESTful API - Develop an algorithm that can create a JSON that can handle external relationships

Tags: php, arrays, json, rest

I'm trying to return a well-formed json containing all the resources related to the requested resource, currently the problem is to get the sub-resources to be arranged correctly one below the other like this:

```
[
   {
      "ID":"1",
      "desc":"Bel post fra",
      "evaluation":"2",
      "Users":{
         "id":"1",
         "imgPath":"defaultICO.png",
         "email":"e@e.com",
         "psw":"d",
         "pswSalt":"d",
         "birthDate":"2004-12-02",
         "actCode":"0",
         "actState":"0"
      },
      "Seasons":{
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Prova Stagione",
         "desc":"prova desc stagione",
         "imagePath":null,
          "Genres":{
         "id":"1",
         "desc":"Horror",
         "icoPath":null
      }
      },
      "Episodes":{
         "id":null,
         "ssn":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "relaseDate":null
      },
      "Productions":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "photoPath":null,
         "relaseYear":null,
         "gne":null,
         "sga":null
      }
     
   }
]
```

Right now, I've managed to build the query construction part dynamically, so the query of a hypothetical call to: GET /Posts is generated like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts  LEFT JOIN Users ON Posts.pst_usr_id=Users.usr_id LEFT JOIN Seasons ON Posts.pst_ssn_id=Seasons.ssn_id LEFT JOIN Episodes ON Posts.pst_epd_id=Episodes.epd_id LEFT JOIN Productions ON Posts.pst_pdc_id=Productions.pdc_id LEFT JOIN Genres ON Seasons.ssn_gne_id=Genres.gne_id
```

This is the call code:

```
public function call($method, $ru)
    {

        $call = new Call(mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn, $ru), $method, $this->tablesStructures);


        $sqlInfo = $call->getSqlQuery();
        $postRows = $this->getTablStrcNRows($this->tablesStructures[$sqlInfo->getResource()]);

        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlInfo->getSql());

        if ($result) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

            $fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);


            $data = array();
            $subsJSON = array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $row_data = array();

                foreach ($fields as $field) {

                    if (isset($this->tablesStructures[$sqlInfo->getResource()])) {
                        if (!in_array($field->name, $this->tablesStructures[$sqlInfo->getResource()]) && $field->table == $sqlInfo->getResource()) {

                            $row_data[explode("_", $field->name)[1]] = $row[$field->name];
                        } else {
                            if ($field->table != $sqlInfo->getResource()) {

                              

                                $row_data[$field->table][explode("_", $field->name)[1]] = $row[$field->name];
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $row_data[explode("_", $field->name)[1]] = $row[$field->name];
                    }
                }

                $data[] = $row_data;
            }
            
            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

So after getting the sql I run it and try to transform my result into a json. To understand the foreign keys of the various tables, my code uses this array in which for now there are only two tables:

```
$this->tablesStructures["Seasons"] = array("_fkField0" => "ssn_gne_id", "_fkTableField0" => "gne_id", "_FKTableName0" => "Genres", "_TableName0" => "Seasons");
        $this->tablesStructures["Posts"] = array(
            "_fkField0" => "pst_usr_id", "_fkTableField0" => "usr_id", "_FKTableName0" => "Users", "_TableName0" => "Posts",
            "_fkField1" => "pst_ssn_id", "_fkTableField1" => "ssn_id", "_FKTableName1" => "Seasons", "_TableName1" => "Posts",
            "_fkField2" => "pst_epd_id", "_fkTableField2" => "epd_id", "_FKTableName2" => "Episodes", "_TableName2" => "Posts",
            "_fkField3" => "pst_pdc_id", "_fkTableField3" => "pdc_id", "_FKTableName3" => "Productions", "_TableName3" => "Posts",
            "_fkField4" => "ssn_gne_id", "_fkTableField4" => "gne_id", "_FKTableName4" => "Genres", "_TableName4" => "Seasons"
        );
```

This is how I use the array in question:

_fkField -> the name of the foreign key in table _TableName

_fkTableField -> the name of the field of the table to which _fkField is related

_FKTableName-> the name of the table where the _fkTableField field is present

so a request like this: GET /Posts should return a json like this:

```
[
   {
      "ID":"1",
      "desc":"Bel post fra",
      "evaluation":"2",
      "Users":{
         "id":"1",
         "imgPath":"defaultICO.png",
         "email":"e@e.com",
         "psw":"d",
         "pswSalt":"d",
         "birthDate":"2004-12-02",
         "actCode":"0",
         "actState":"0"
      },
      "Seasons":{
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Prova Stagione",
         "desc":"prova desc stagione",
         "imagePath":null,
          "Genres":{
         "id":"1",
         "desc":"Horror",
         "icoPath":null
      }
      },
      "Episodes":{
         "id":null,
         "ssn":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "relaseDate":null
      },
      "Productions":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "photoPath":null,
         "relaseYear":null,
         "gne":null,
         "sga":null
      }
     
   }
]
```

instead the json is in another way because the code I wrote only allows you to consider direct relationships with the requested resource and not tables related to other tables that are related to the requested resource, in fact the json is like this:

but it is so:

```
[
   {
      "ID":"1",
      "desc":"Bel post fra",
      "evaluation":"2",
      "Users":{
         "id":"1",
         "imgPath":"defaultICO.png",
         "email":"e@e.com",
         "psw":"d",
         "pswSalt":"d",
         "birthDate":"2004-12-02",
         "actCode":"0",
         "actState":"0"
      },
      "Seasons":{
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Prova Stagione",
         "desc":"prova desc stagione",
         "imagePath":null,
          
      },
      "Episodes":{
         "id":null,
         "ssn":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "relaseDate":null
      },
      "Productions":{
         "id":null,
         "name":null,
         "desc":null,
         "photoPath":null,
         "relaseYear":null,
         "gne":null,
         "sga":null
      },
"Genres":{
         "id":"1",
         "desc":"Horror",
         "icoPath":null
      }
     
   }
]
```

In this case for example taking for example this json Genres it is as if it were a table related to post when in reality it is a table related to Season, and Season is related to post.
**what would be a solution to implement for generate the json correctly?**